# Error accessing files on my domain with wordpress running

Tags: wordpress

Not so much a coding question, but I searched the web and couldn't find an answer so I am turning to you. I am developing a wordpress website on my domain which I at the same time use to upload my school projects. However whenever I try to access the html file of my school project it shows me a a default wordpress "page not foud" page. Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

This is my file folder on cpanel. I am trying to access a file in API ASGNMNT with URL: [www.leanart.co/API%20ASGNMNT/mui.html](http://www.leanart.co/API%20ASGNMNT/mui.html)

[image: This is my file folder on cpanel. I am trying to access a file in API ASGNMNT.]

Comment: **Too Broad**. What is the url example you're trying to access? where is your files in the folder? where is wordpress installation?

Comment: place your folder into `public_html` folder and try to access it with the url you provided. Also, bad experience to use spaces in the folder/file names

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now! I usually use underscores, but I was too lazy to reupload when I noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `public_html` folder is the **web root** for your **primary domain name**.
>   This means that `public_html` is the folder where you put all website
>   files which you want to appear when someone types your main domain.

You can't access outside of your **web root** folder using domain name.

Just moving your folder with `.html` files to `public_html` folder will make them accessible with domain name:

`http://{your-domain-name}/{your-folder-name}/{your-file-name}.html`